# jQuery: Function is not working

Tags: jquery, function

I need to get this

```
('th:last').siblings();
```

properly into the **not** area of this

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "td:not(....)", function() 
{
    /// further code... 
});
```

How does this work?

Comment: what are the siblings of `th`?

Comment: the siblings of th are td elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a css selector for siblings like `~`:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "td:not(th:last ~ thesiblingTag)", function() {
```

```js
$('th:last ~ td').css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>aaa</th>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>aaa</th>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>aaa</th>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```